# Can browser split up payload data into multiple websocket frames?

Tags: javascript, c++, websocket

In javascript below i send up to 200 bytes through websocket (after connecting and handshaking ):

```
     buf= new Uint8Array(200);
     /* filling buf with data*/
     ws.send(buf.buffer);
```

On the other side there is a simple iocp c++ server, which receive these 200 bytes preceded by few bytes of websocket frame.

Can i assume that browser always send these 200 bytes(+ websocket head) in one piece? 
Or should I always on server side check if this is final frame (by checking first bit in websocket head)?

thanks in advance for yours tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always check the FIN bit, as per RFC6455 it is perfectly possible that the browser splits up the payload (depending on some upper limit for a web socket frame).